# How To Improve The Utilization of Multi-Core CPU In Tensorflow2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using tensorflow2 on Windows, and the Utilization rate on CPU is Extremely Low, SO I look up the task manager, and there is only ONE  CORE  Working
[image: screenshot]

then I search on the internet add The following code in the front of my code, which makes no difference

`tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(48) tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(48)`

how can i fix it. The following is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(48)
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(48)

def build_model(layer1=10, layer2=10):

    model = keras.Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(layer1, kernel_initializer='he_normal', input_shape=[11]))
    model.add(Dense(layer2, kernel_initializer='he_normal'))

    model.add(Dense(10, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='softmax'))

    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0015)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=optimizer)

    return model

model = built_model()
model.fit(x, y)
```

Comment: I think an important question is, what functions of tensorflow you expect to be parallelized

Comment: Thank you for your comment,  If I understand you correctly, you mean i hadn't set the right model ? what should i do to achieve that?

Comment: This model is too small to benefit from multiple cores, you are not putting enough computation, what makes you think multicore is even needed?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I run a more difficult model, and the CPU utilization improved a lot, which prove you are right, Thank you for your advise!